# Code links only when static library compiled in C++ mode in Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker-errors

I have created a WIN32 static library of a [linked list manager](https://github.com/solaremperor/cLinkedList) that I have been using for C/C++ development.

I compiled this library on Visual Studio 2019, forcing it compile as C code (`/TC` option in VS2019 preferences). However, I did use the

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

in the header just in case my static library would be used by a C++ program. Here is a link to the [header](https://github.com/solaremperor/cLinkedList/blob/main/include/cLinkedList.h).

But, when I use this static library in a C++ project, I get linker errors

```
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned long __cdecl cListLength(struct _cLinkedList *)" (?cListLength@@YAKPAU_cLinkedList@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl quickDAQstart(void)" (?quickDAQstart@@YAXXZ)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cListEmpty(struct _cLinkedList *)" (?cListEmpty@@YAHPAU_cLinkedList@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl setSampleClockTiming(enum _sampling_modes,double,char *,enum _trigger_modes,unsigned __int64,bool)" (?setSampleClockTiming@@YAXW4_sampling_modes@@NPADW4_trigger_modes@@_K_N@Z)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct _cListElem * __cdecl cListFirstElem(struct _cLinkedList *)" (?cListFirstElem@@YAPAU_cListElem@@PAU_cLinkedList@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl enumerateNIDevices(void)" (?enumerateNIDevices@@YAXXZ)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct _cListElem * __cdecl cListNextElem(struct _cLinkedList *,struct _cListElem *)" (?cListNextElem@@YAPAU_cListElem@@PAU_cLinkedList@@PAU1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl enumerateNIDevices(void)" (?enumerateNIDevices@@YAXXZ)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl cListFirstData(struct _cLinkedList *)" (?cListFirstData@@YAPAXPAU_cLinkedList@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl syncSampling(void)" (?syncSampling@@YAXXZ)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cListInit(struct _cLinkedList *)" (?cListInit@@YAHPAU_cLinkedList@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl enumerateNIDevices(void)" (?enumerateNIDevices@@YAXXZ)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cListAppend(struct _cLinkedList *,void *)" (?cListAppend@@YAHPAU_cLinkedList@@PAX@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl enumerateNIDevices(void)" (?enumerateNIDevices@@YAXXZ)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cListPrepend(struct _cLinkedList *,void *)" (?cListPrepend@@YAHPAU_cLinkedList@@PAX@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl pinMode(unsigned int,enum _IOmodes,unsigned int)" (?pinMode@@YAXIW4_IOmodes@@I@Z)
1>quickDAQ.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cListUnlinkElem(struct _cLinkedList *,struct _cListElem *)" (?cListUnlinkElem@@YAXPAU_cLinkedList@@PAU_cListElem@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl enumerateNIDevices(void)" (?enumerateNIDevices@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\tyros\codebase\testingLinkedList\Debug\testingLinkedList.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "testingLinkedList.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Clearly, the linker fails to link to the static library.

However, if I compile the static library using the compile as flag set to C++ (`/TP`), the project in which I am using this library compiles without the aforementioned errors.

Why is this?

Comment: My guess is that you should tell extern C also on the sources and not just the header? The extern C keyword tells the compiler to not mangle names, and this is done for the headers, but if not for the sources, you have unreferenced symbols.

Comment: extern "C" should have worked.  So the compiler is probably #including another .h file.  Diagnose with Project > Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > "Show Includes" and C/C++ > Preprocessor > "Preprocess to a File".

Comment: Thank you for your responses. While putting extern C in the source file doesn't help, your pointers to check for unreferenced symbols and showing includes led me to realize that PEBKAC happened. I wasn't including the modified header files to my new project that was using the static library. [SMH]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was PEBKAC. I forgot to include the new headers (that had the extern "C" defintions for C++) along with the new version of the static library. This caused the C++ project which used the library to mangle symbols.

Moral of the story - Always change out both the header and static library when updating libraries used by a C++ project.